# ERROR in my minecraft bot discord.py . KeyError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_shards_data()
    shards_amt = users[str(user.id)]["shards"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.author.name} SHARDS',color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name="SHARDS ", value=shards_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name ="TOTAL ITEMS", value = "`stone` `coal` `iron` `gold` `redstone` `emerald` `diamond`", inline = False)
    em.add_field(name = "YOUR ITEMS", value = "Type s;inventory or s;inv to view your items list")             
    await ctx.send(embed= em)

@bot.command(aliases=['inv'])
async def inventory(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    
    users = await get_items_data()
    
    stone_amt = users[str(user.id)]["stone"]
    coal_amt = users[str(user.id)]["coal"]
    iron_amt = users[str(user.id)]["iron"]
    gold_amt = users[str(user.id)]["gold"]
    redstone_amt = users[str(user.id)]["redstone"]
    emerald_amt = users[str(user.id)]["emerald"]
    diamond_amt = users[str(user.id)]["diamond"]
    
    em = discord.Embed(title=f'{ctx.author.name} INVENTORY',color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name="STONES", value=stone_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="COAL", value=coal_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="IRON", value=iron_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="GOLD", value=gold_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="REDSTONE", value=redstone_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="EMERALD", value= emerald_amt, inline = False)
    em.add_field(name="DIAMOND", value=diamond_amt, inline = False)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    

@bot.command()
async def mine(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_shards_data()
    a = 9, 10, 16, 23, 11, 26
    b = "stone", "coal", "iron", "gold", "redstone", "emerald", "diamond","stone", "coal" ,"iron", "stone"
    c = random.choice(a)
    d = random.choice(b)
    e = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 9, 14, 13, 16, 18,20
    f = random.choice(e)
    em = discord.Embed(title = f'{ctx.author.name} you mined the ground')
    em.add_field(name = "SHARDS", value = f"`You got {c} shards`", inline = False)
    em.add_field(name = "ITEMS", value = f"`You got {f} {d}`")
    await ctx.send(embed =em)

    users[str(user.id)]["shards"] += c

    if d == "stone":
        users[str(user.id)]["stone"] += f

    elif d == "coal":
        users[str(user.id)]["coal"] += f

    elif d == "iron":
        users[str(user.id)]["iron"] += f

    else:
        users[str(user.id)]["gold"] += f
        
        
    with open("items.json", 'r') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    with open("shards.json",'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
```

I am trying to make a minecraft bot in which my i get random shards and items after mining, shards are updating in my shards balance but, the items are not updating and in inventory command it is giving error.Pease tell how to do i am facing difficulty in it

```
Ignoring exception in command mine:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding and editing\discord bot\Mezuhashi.py", line 79, in mine
    users[str(user.id)]["coal"] += f
KeyError: 'coal'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'coal'
```

THE MINE COMMAND ERROR

```
Ignoring exception in command inventory:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding and editing\discord bot\Mezuhashi.py", line 36, in inventory
    stone_amt = users[str(user.id)]["stone"]
KeyError: '773913180271280129'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '773913180271280129'
```

THE INVENTORY COMMAND ERROR

Comment: Try printing out `users[str(user.id)]`. Most likely there isn't a `coal` key. For the inventory error seems like there is no key that matches your user.id

Comment: If you don't know for certain that every user will contain every item, then use `coal_amt = users[str(user.id)].get("coal",0)`.